# How to supress crystal report section based on codition

Tags: crystal-reports

How to supress crystal report section based on condition. When this booleen flag is true then supress else dont supress

```
If{Table.FlagCustomerLotNumber}=True
Then False
Else True
```

But this one does not work

Comment: In short you can just write: `{Table.FlagCustomerLotNumber}`

Comment: How it will supress then @RobertNiestroj.. Please suggest

Comment: Doesnt work. @RobertNiestroj

Comment: What is the type of database field lot number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Section Expert, select the section to suppress. Then check the box next to "Suppress", click the formula button (looks like x+2 with a pencil), and enter your formula there. For a boolean value you only have to enter the field, like this:

```
{Table.FlagCustomerLotNumber}
```

This will suppress if the flag is true and not if false.